# Stripping decimal point of floating point number

Tags: python, strip

Why isn't it possible to strip the decimal point off of a float?

`str(1.5).strip(".")` returns `1.5`

Why doesn't it return `15`?

Has the decimal point an own symbol that is not equal with the full stop `.`?

Answer (score 4):

`str.strip()` only removes characters at the beginning and end, not in the middle. It's mostly used for removing extraneous whitespace around a line of input (with no argument, it defaults to removing whitespace).

Use `str.replace()` to replace a string anywhere:

```
str(1.5).replace('.', '')
```